# Can't drop an airport

Tags: simcity-2013

I'm unable to drop an airport in my city. It's my first time trying to create one, but it's always red.

When I move it to an open area it says `must plop on snap point!`. What does that mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just made an airport, and I struggled a bit myself.
But you need the road where the house of the airport is, on the side, (either side) cause it will switch sides to where you put the road.

Not a road all the way along side the runway, but the terminal section ;)

Comment: The snap point is on the side of the terminal building opposite the runway.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot place most (if not all) buildings and other ploppable items in an open area, it must be connected to a road.

The snap points it's referring to are the little blue dots that appear next to roads or other structures where you may place it.  The road typically has to be at least as long as the edge of the building you are placing and the lot big and flat enough to be placed.  Otherwise you will not be able to place the building.

Comment: Do you know on which side of the airport it wants to connect with? I'll have to destroy some stuff to make room.

Comment: I actually haven't gotten a large enough city to be able to make use of it so I don't know. The server downtime and just overall buggy regions is preventing me from making any more progress. My cities are tearing themselves apart because nothing is working. I'm going to wait this out before I get in deep into the game.

Comment: Me too... one of my cities is completely dead because I can't import electricity from another city. Other cities have extra power, but it appears the servers won't let me buy it.

Comment: I've been pretty successful at trading services (power/water/police/etc) between cities the last day or so. Where it is still pretty wonky is commuting workers / students and, more worrisome, the can't connect to the servers warning comes up way to often.